# Programmatically check if two classes are linear separable

Tags: svm, dataset, linear-model

How to programmatically check if two classes are linear separable? (only yes/no answer)

Maybe I can train linear SVM on data(use parameters to overfit) and then run test on same data  and if accuracy will be 100% dataset is linear separable.

Comment: You could, but you'd be making your life more complicated. Look at the answer to this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/45831/603)

Comment: @user603 what algorithm used in this test? " This boils down to solving a linear programming problem."

Comment: you can find it [here](http://ora.ouls.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:8f9ee0d0-d78e-4101-9ab4-f9cbceed2a2a). The main contribution of the author is to frame the problem as an L.P.