# MSE huge when estimating regression from small samples

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am trying to test the predictive accuracy of regression using training sets of varying sizes.

```
Y <- rnorm(100)
X <- replicate(5, Y+rnorm(100) )   
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Y,X))
```

Let's say the training set is 2% of the data:

```
train <- nrow(data) * 0.02
test <- nrow(data) - train
```

I repeat the process for 1000 times:

```
MSE <- vector()
for( i in 1:1000){

train.elements <- sample(1:nrow(data),train)
train.set <- data[train.elements,]
test.set <- data[setdiff(1:nrow(data), train.elements),]

# then I fit a regression model:

    model <- lm(train.set[,1]~ train.set[,2]+train.set[,3]+train.set[,4]+train.set[,5])

#I now use this model to predict the values in the test set:
predictions <- predict.lm(model,data=test.set)

MSE[i] <- mean((test.set[,1] - predictions)^2)

}
```

My problem is that due to the small sample size the MSE sometimes is extremely huge.

Is this normal? I am unable to plot a curve of the MSE as a function of training set size because the MSE for small sample sizes are so large.

Comment: Please see my edit I forgot to divide by 1/test set size. Is this correct now?

On real data I still get enormous estimates sometimes.

Comment: Looks better. Why don't you simply use `mean`?

Comment: I replaced it with mean. I still get enormous estimates with some of the real world data I am working with. Most of the time the MSE is a small number but occasionally it ends up with a huge estimate like 4000.

Answer (score 3):

When I just ran your code a few times, my maximum MSE was 9.6. Still a lot, but not 4000. You may want to use `set.seed()` to make your analysis reproducible.

Your dataset has just 100 rows. You use 2% of that for model fitting, that is, just two data points. You try to fit five independent variables.  R therefore uses the first IV (`train.set[,2]`) and puts a straight line through your two data points, discarding the other three IVs.

Then, in predicting, you simply extrapolate the `[,2]` component of your test set along the straight line you fit.

And of course, your straight line is enormously variable. The slope can differ extremely, since you just picked two lines at random. (Since your `Y` has zero relationship to the IVs, the correct slope should be zero.) If you get a large slope simply because of the variability of your parameter estimate, you will get predictions that are *far* away from where they should be.

Don't fit five IVs to just two data points. Rules of thumb suggest at least 15 or 20 data points per degree of freedom.