# Logistic regression with two variables, one is derived from other, is not coming out statistically significant

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I have two variables in a dataset. First variable has a continuous value (`AHI`) and other one is a binomial variable (`OSA_status`) which I have created based on the value of my first variable (`AHI`). i.e.  if `AHI> 5` then `OSA_status = 1` else `OSA_status = 0`. I am trying out a logistic regression with dependent variable, `OSA_status (0/1)` and independent variable, `AHI`. I was expecting `AHI` will be significantly associated with `OSA_status` as it is derived from the independent variable itself `(AHI)`. But my result is as follows. Can someone please explain me why i got this result.

```
Call:
glm(formula = OSA_status ~ AHI, family = "binomial", data = pre_surgery)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-5.277e-04  -2.000e-08  -2.000e-08   2.000e-08   5.818e-04  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    517.7    36115.6   0.014    0.989
AHI           -104.6     7314.3  -0.014    0.989

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1.1829e+02  on 87  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 6.1704e-07  on 86  degrees of freedom
AIC: 4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25

Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model seems to have [perfect separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/separation/info). Notice the large standard errors of the coefficient estimates, and the tell-tale warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Your model never actually got fit by the software! As you provided a fixed cutoff of `AHI > 5` for defining `OSA_status`, without any probabilistic element, this isn't very surprising. A logistic regression will have trouble with fitting when there actually is a cutoff that exactly distinguishes 2 groups.

For ways to deal with perfect separation, see for example [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45803/28500).

For the dangers of breaking a continuous predictor into discrete categories, see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your `OSA_status` variable is coded as factor and the other `AHI` as numeric?

You could try the opposite and give a result?
An Anova as following?

```r
rstatix::anova_test(pre_surgery, AHI ~ OSA_status)
```

If you do not find any result here, it might be that you made a mistake when coding your `OSA_status` variable.