# Negative Binomial Regression Not Running in R

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I’m having some issues with event count analysis in R, and I welcome any help I can get. I’ll walk through my issue as (to me) it seems rather bizarre.

It starts off when I try to run a negative binomial and a zero-inflated negative binomial to compare the two in a Vuong test (I have a lot of zeroes, but it’s really unclear on whether or not my data is sufficiently zero-inflated). Below, I have copied the code for the negative binomial:

`test_nb <- glm.nb(low_lvl_deaths ~ CSO_prtcpt + IMR + ethnic_frac + democracy + cumulative_intensity + PKO + war_duration + territory + peace_agg + con_complex + lGDPpc, data = nb_outliers)`

However, in an attempt to estimate the test negative binomial model, I am met with the following error:

`Error in glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, etastart = eta, offset = offset, : NA/NaN/Inf in ‘x’`

(For further information, I get no errors at all when I run the exact same DV and set of covariates, but with a Poisson model instead)

To my understanding, this means that I have NA, NaN, or infinite values in my data set. However, after examining this, I only have NA values (which to my knowledge, should be naturally omitted regardless). To contextualize the issue, I am able to run a Cox model with the same covariates with no issues such as this. Obviously, I have a different dependent variable between the Cox model and negative binomial, but there are no NaN or infinite values in the DV for the negative binomial.

So, what I did next was run the model repeatedly, removing one covariate at a time. What I found was that, when I remove the peace_agg variable (a dummy), the initial error goes away. However, I get gifted with a new one:

`Warning messages: 1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 2: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge`

The only thing I can do to change this (but not fix) is exclude the ethnic_frac variable, which simply only gives me 1 “algorithm did not converge” warning, rather than 2.

So I’m really stuck with 2 questions. First, why on earth does excluding the peace_agg variable (a dummy, with no NAs/NaNs/Infinite values) resolve the initial warning error? Second, how do I go about resolving this algorithm not converging warning? I have heard solutions such as “increase iterations” and “specify theta”, but I’m simply not sure how to do this in a manner that isn’t completely arbitrary.

Comment: I think this might be an example of a perfect separation phenomenon. Some threads: (1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression (2) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45803/logistic-regression-in-r-resulted-in-perfect-separation-hauck-donner-phenomenon (3) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45803/logistic-regression-in-r-resulted-in-perfect-separation-hauck-donner-phenomenon

Comment: @Sycorax while the exact error is the same, note that the `glm.nb` is a generalization of the Poisson model which, on its own, isn't subject to perfect separation. I did provide an answer pointing out how a bad estimate of `theta` - the ancillary dispersion parameter - could cause this, and how to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

The most useful diagnostic is to make use of the `trace` option in `glm.nb`. According to the documentation you can trace either the `glm` step or the `theta` estimation step. The GLM steps work by initiating the theta using a non-dispersed Poisson model, using the residuals, a method of moments estimator for theta is obtained, and input to the next negative binomial regression. Recall the negative binomial model uses theta in the expression for the variance, so it's theoretically possible that divergent results are obtained because theta is calculated to be 0 exactly. Recall, theta would be zero if you have a perfect prediction, i.e. the combination of covariates is of dimension greater than or equal to the number of rows of data. Another name for this is a saturated model framework. Anyway, you don't have data examples or trace output in the question so there's nothing more that can be said. If this turns out to be the case, I think you might need to scale back the covariate selection to something less willy-nilly. If this really is simply badness in the MOM estimator of theta, you can use a quasipoisson model as a kind of one-step estimator of the negative binomial model.