# Predictor variable is perfectly correlated with the response variable yet the coefficient is insignificant

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

Predictor variable has the correlation value of -0.98 to the binary response (with classes 1 and 2). However, logistic regression coefficient come out to be insignificant. The residual deviance of the model is also significantly low. What can be the reason behind this? How is it possible to have a model with significant coefficients? The code and output is below.

```
fit <- glm(blType==1 ~ gammaSupRatio, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df)
summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = blType == 1 ~ gammaSupRatio, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.15354  -0.15354   0.00002   0.00002   2.98214  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -4.4348     0.5808  -7.636 2.24e-14 ***
gammaSupRatio   18.0006  2008.1727   0.009    0.993    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 709.712  on 511  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  32.644  on 510  degrees of freedom
AIC: 36.644

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 21
```

Comment: Is "-0.98" Pearson correlation?

Comment: @Zhanxiong Yes it is.

Comment: You have perfect (or near-perfect) separation. Very high log-odds for the coefficient but near infinite standard errors, because your model fits (almost) perfectly. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression) and others about the [Hauck-Donner phenomenon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45803/28500).

Comment: Have you tried using Firth logistic regression, i.e., `logistif::flic()`, instead of regular logistic regression? It is specifically designed to deal with cases with near perfect separation and is less biased than usual logistic regression.

Comment: There is almost perfect separation. Class 2 has high predictor variable level and class 1 has the lower level with 3 exceptions. The message of the data is clear. However, it should have been in the model and I need an explainable model.

Comment: In that case, the first link by @EdM seems to be a duplicate that addresses how to deal with such a situation.

Comment: @Dave The issue is the perfect separation in the link. The question here is about the insignificant coefficient of a predictor variable that near-perfectly separates the response variable. Although problems root from the same cause this outcome wasn't present in the link.

Comment: @Noah that method seems to deal well against separation issues. Also, it provides an interpretable model with statistical tests on independent variables. Thanks for the answer.