# mice: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge

Tags: r, missing-data, mice

I have a dataset with about 12 categorical variables with levels ranging from 2 - 10, as well as other numerical variables. About 280 records. I'm using the `mice` package in `r` to perform imputation on the missing data with all default settings. 
However, when I try to do the imputation like this:

```
imp <- mice(df)
```

I continue to get this warning:

```
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

The solutions I found online [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596160/why-am-i-getting-algorithm-did-not-converge-and-fitted-prob-numerically-0-or) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5354/logistic-regression-model-does-not-converge) only focus on using the `glm` function directly, but in my case, it's a function that's called from within `mice`. I've tried setting `maxit = 50`, like this

```
imp <- mice(df, maxit = 50)
```

but only ended up getting many more instances of the same warning. Any idea what could be causing this?