# For the Logistic model, why is the objective function unbounded below if two sets are linearly seperated?

Tags: logistic, optimization, separation

I am reading *Approximate linear discrimination via logistic modeling* in the Section 8.6.1 of B & V's [Convex Optimization book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf). On Page 428,

$$
\operatorname{minimize} \  -l(a, b)   \tag{8.27}
$$

with variables $a$, $b$, where $l$ is the log-likelihood function

$$
\begin{aligned}
&l(a, b)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(a^{T} x_{i}-b\right)-\sum_{i=1}^{N} \log \left(1+\exp \left(a^{T} x_{i}-b\right)\right)-\sum_{i=1}^{M} \log \left(1+\exp \left(a^{T} y_{i}-b\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

It says that if two sets can be linearly seperated, i.e., if there exist $a$, $b$ with $a^T x_i > b$ and $a^T y_i < b$, then the optimization problem (8.27) is unbounded below. **Why is it unbounded below for this case?**

Comment: We already have many interesting discussions on this topic. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254124/why-does-logistic-regression-become-unstable-when-classes-are-well-separated https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239928/is-there-any-intuitive-explanation-of-why-logistic-regression-will-not-work-forv https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5354/logistic-regression-model-does-not-converge?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

[image: Fitted linear regression for increasing values of b]

Here's an answer that takes a look at what actually happens to the fit. Consider the example of $x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that the data is linearly separable at $x=0$. We model the data using linear regression without an intercept, i.e.:

$y = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(x b)}$.

Now as you can see in the plot above, as b increases, the fit gets increasingly close to the true data (black points). Hence, the best fit would be for infinite b, and thus the problem is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the simplest case where there is a single predictor that is binary, i.e., you are using the binary logistic model to compute two proportions.  If P(Y=1 | X=0) = 1 and P(Y=1 | X=1) = 0 you have perfect separation.  The estimated proportions are 1.0 and 0.0 and there is no problem with the log likelihood function, which is zero.